# Lost node when insert to head

Tags: c, data-structures

when I insert node to head , it doesn't work. but insert to other location works well.

here is my insert function

```
int insert_before(ListNode *head, ListNode *p, int x){ 
ListNode *tmp, *cursor;
if(head == NULL || p == NULL) return -1;                                                                                                         
if(head == p){ 
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
    tmp->val = x;
    // insert node
    tmp->next = p;
    p = tmp;

    printf("insert before: \n");
    printList(head);
    return 0;
}   
cursor = head;
while(cursor->next != p && cursor->next != NULL ) cursor = cursor->next;
tmp = malloc(sizeof(ListNode));
tmp->val = x;
//insert node
tmp->next = p;
cursor->next = tmp;


printf("insert before: \n");
printList(head);
return 0;
```

}

my main function

```
int main(){
ListNode *head, *tmp;
int x=0;
int arr[5] = {1,2,4,5,6};
head =  createList(arr, 5);
printList(head);
tmp = get_by_index(head,3);

// insert
//insert_after(head, x);
 insert_before(head, tmp, 100);
// insert_before(head, head, 100);
printf("in main: ");
printList(head);

printf("insert_before return %d \n", x);
return 0;
```

}

when I run insert_before(head, tmp,x), it works fine
[image]
，
when I run insert_before(head,head,100);
it have no changes;

Comment: As implied by its name, function `insert_before` should update the variable `head` to point to the newly created head of the list. At its present implementation, it is impossible since you are passing this variable by value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

inserting to head of linked list replaces its head, you cannot do it with function foo(node *head). Instead, you should pass pointer of pointer of head, so that the function can change it.

Comment: Thanks, I think my question is duplicated with   [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6810359/modifying-head-pointer-in-a-linked-list)

Answer (score 0):

You have to change syntax of your code little bit,

```
int insert_before(ListNode **head, ListNode *p, int x)
```

I think you got it what i am trying to say here.